# Two Sync calls using webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have to 2 calls that should be in sync .It needs to call db and get some data and after that it should use that data and call other db to get other data. But when I am trying to call the other function CountDownLatch getCount return 1 and the function blocks forever

Function where i am wrapping two calls

```
 return getDataDB1call()
                .flatMap(doc -> {
                     return Flux.fromIterable(doc.getChange().entrySet())
                                    .flatMap(stringStringEntry -> getDocumentXDb2(stringStringEntry));
                        });
```

I am able to get the doc in first step but when calling getFunctionDB2 it goes to a forever blocking state.

Function for gettingDoucumentfromDB2

```
Flux<FeedResponse<Document>> feedResponseFlux = RxJava2Adapter.observableToFlux(
               RxJavaInterop.toV2Observable(client.queryDocuments(collectionPath, sqlQuerySpec, feedOptions)), BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

       return feedResponseFlux
               .next()
               .map(feedResponse -> {
                   try {
                       CosmosDBPage<DocumentX> page = new CosmosDBPage();
                       page.setContinuationToken(feedResponse.getResponseContinuation());
                       page.setResponseObjects(feedResponse.getResults().stream().map(doc -> doc.toObject(DocumentX.class)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                       return  page;
                       }
```

When i am blocking this call to get a list of DocumentX it goes to a forever blocking state